# Unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory in Airflow (Docker)

Tags: docker, gcc, pip, dockerfile, airflow

I'm trying to install dbt-core and dbt-redshift in Airflow (Docker) but when I do so I get the error

```
 #9 51.00     unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
 #9 51.00     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried installing gcc with docker build but i still get the same error. My Dockerfile looks like this. Requirements contain dbt-core and dbt-redshift only

```
 FROM python:3.7
 RUN apt-get update
 RUN apt-get install gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 libffi-dev unixodbc-dev -y

 FROM apache/airflow:2.1.2
 COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
 RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r /requirements.txt
```

If i build the first command separately it finishes successfully and it looks like gcc gets installed. But then i build the second command and i get the same error again.

Comment: The second stage fails because there is no gcc installed there. You would need to install it there.